# Laravel - How to change upload file path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to upload images to folder project images.

My project structure folder in share host is this:

```
- css
- images
- fonts
- js
- laravel-code
- .htaccess
```

Inside `laravel-code` folder are the remaining files.

The site work well, show images well but when i upload a new image it save the image in `laravel-code/` and create this folders `public/images` ...

I want to save images in image folder at root directory.

How can I do that?

When I do an upload file it detects if it was a pdf or other file; if it was pdf saves file on storage folder, if it other file (images) save in images folder. This is my code... I think I cannot use `public_path`

```
if (false === stripos($name, '-pdf')) {
    $basePath = trim(public_path(), '/');
    $newPath = trim(public_path('images'), '/');
} else {
    $basePath = trim(storage_path(), '/');
    $newPath = trim(storage_path(), '/');
}
```

Comment: what happens in else part.. ??

Comment: it's a pdf file that have to be stored in storage path. @RïshïKêshKümar

Comment: When you try to save an image, do you get any errors on the screen?

Comment: no! it save the image in laravel-code/public/images ... and i want that create outside of laravel-code folder in images folder. @AlfredoEM

Comment: try using base_path helper instead public_path

Comment: base_path() go to /laravel-code and i want to go to one folder back like ../laravel-code @AlfredoEM

Answer (score 0):

To get the full path to the parent of the root directory, you will need to use PHP's built in [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function.

The first argument indicates the directory to be evaluated. The second argument is the level of parent directories you want to traverse, in your example, only one level up.

```
$root = base_path();
$parent = dirname($root, 1);
```