# Laravel - How to upload file to a different folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I'm developing a website that upload file to `public/images` but in my sharing host i have a different structure so the upload doesn't work well.

My structure is that:

```
- css
- images(I WANT TO UPLOAD TO THIS FOLDER)
- fonts
- js
- laravel-code
-.htaccess
```

If i do echo `base_path()` i get `/laravel-code` but i need to back and i don't know how.

If use `public_path` it creates a `/public/images` inside `laravel-code` folder and i don't want that.

How can i save images in my images folder?

Thank you

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a folder in your /storage/ directory and to create a symlink to the desired public folder (/public/images) then.

Comment: please check if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790565/4874281

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - How to change upload file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218805/laravel-how-to-change-upload-file-path)

Answer (score 1):

**ok. try it**

```
        public function upload(Request $request)
        {
            $imageName = 'testing';
            $file = $request->file('picture');
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move("images/", "{$imageName}.{$ext}");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
base_path() . "/../images/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your path is public/images then, simply you can use destination path as 'images/' and then move the file to destination like this:

```
/* check Request has file or not */
if($request->hasFile('file')){

    /* get File from Request */
    $file = $request->file('file');

    /* get File Extension */
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    /* Your File Destination */
    $destination = 'images/';

    /* unique Name for file */
    $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $_extension;

    /* finally move file to your destination */
    $file->move($destination, $filename);
}
```